# Unity Tag Triggering

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
void onCollisionEnter(Collision test)
{
        if (xTag.gameObject.tag == "Row 0, Col 0")
        {
            Debug.Log("X");
        }
}
```

And so my problem is I have two game objects (xTag and yTag) and when they touch the R0C0 game object (which happens to just be a box collider) I want it to print out as a test. The two game objects xTag and yTag, and I have an array that I made and I add to an Array if xTag or yTag touches on R0C0 and so fourth. My problem is that I am now testing and so that if the game object touches the other game object with the tag it prints this. Both xTag and YTag have tags along with the the colliders but nothing is working!

Comment: So, `xTag` and `yTag` are mobile, and the gameObject with tag `R0C0` doesn't move, right? It kind of looks like you're checking whether `xTag` has the `R0C0` tag, rather than the object you're colliding with, represented with the `Collision test` argument. Just to clarify, which game object does this behavior belong to?

Answer (score 1):

You should be checking what `test.collider.tag` is. xTag's tag will always be the same. you should check that `test.collider.tag == xTag.tag` assuming that `onColliderEnter` is on R0C0.

Source: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collision.html